# Cookie cannot be accessed from another tab

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am working on a laravel project where I need 5-page questionnaire before the register, so I am using cookies to store the answer until user registers. 
Now, I have used the below code to save the request to the cookie

```
        setcookie('step1', json_encode($request->except('_token', 'step')), time()+360000);
```

Now, this step1 cookie is accessible from the same page, but if I try to get this step1 cookie from another tab in the same browser I cannot get it. Please help

Comment: laravel version 5.8

Comment: Why you didn't use Session?

Comment: If a user closes his window by any issue I want to resume from the step where he left @TalhaF.